# Jquery : Display hidden image on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've to fadein an image that is set to display:none, This is what i'm doing that is not working for me

**HTML :**

```
<img src="img/myimg.jpg" id="img">
```

**CSS :**

```
#img{
    display:none;
}
```

**JS :**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#img').fadeIn();                     
    }
});
```

Comment: Should work, see **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/66/)**.

Comment: i also tried to add an alert and that works but   this does not work  dont know whats wrong , with it

Comment: Check the developpers console in your browser.

Comment: thats blank before and after the scroll

Comment: I think you have to put your code inside ready function, check the answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add your code inside `ready()` function :

```js
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#img').fadeIn();                     
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#img{
    display:none;
} 

body{
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://assets.entrepreneur.com/content/16x9/822/20141230193127-work.jpeg" id="img"/>
```

Comment: yes adding ready handler worked , such stupid mistake from me , thank u my friend

Answer (score 0):

jquery `.fadeIn()` won't override display:none; It might work if you use `opacity: 0;` and `visibility: hidden;` as your style rules.

You could also try `$('#img').hide();` right when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $("#img").hide();
    }
    else{
      $("#img").show();
    }
```

This will hide and show the image when you scroll the window down and up, very useful